# Sectional curvature on product manifold of spheres.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Following exercise:

Let $g_n, g_m$ be standard metrics on the spheres $S^n, S^m$, respectively. 
Now define the metric $g=\dfrac{1}{a}g_n+\dfrac{1}{b}g_m$ on $M:=S^n \times S^m$. 
 I need to show, that it holds $K(\Pi)\in [0, max(a,b)]$ for the sectional curvature.

Now I already know that $K(\Pi)=0$ for $\Pi=span(x_n,x_m)$ with $x_n \in S^n, x_m \in S^m$.

My problem is, that I don't know what the length of a tangent vector in the standard metric is..
Can somebody give a hint?

Comment: The question you *should* be thinking about is how the $g$ length of $(X,0)$ is related to the $g_n$ length of $X$.

Comment: Well, that should be $g((X,0),(X,0))=1/a g_n(X,X)$, right?

Comment: And lengths are ... ?